# ¿Cómo añadir los controles de "acelerar", "decelerar", "rebobinar" y "adelantar" en un vídeo en Windows Forms? (Visual Studio, C#, Winforms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Estoy trabajando en Visual Studio (2019), en la interfaz de Windows Forms con C#. La aplicación permite reproducir el vídeo que el usuario elija y tengo que añadir los siguientes controles: play, pause, stop, acelerar y decelerar velocidad, adelantar y retroceder en el vídeo (para que el usuario pueda manejar el vídeo a su antojo). Pero solo sé crear los tres primeros, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Es posible añadir en un vídeo de Windows Forms los controles 'acelerar', 'decelerar', 'rebobinar' y 'adelantar'?  Si la respuesta es afirmativa, ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

Comment: Entiendo que lo que buscas es crear unos controles propios y no usar una libreria que te lo haga ya no? PD: El codigo siempre en formato **texto**

Comment: @Capt.Teach Bueno, no me importa si están ya en una librería o los tengo que crear yo, ¿sabes cómo hacerlo? Y ¿qué quieres decir con lo de el código siempre en formato texto? (estoy muy perdida en el mundo de la programación, lo siento)

Comment: No entiendo muy bien. Debes acceder a `Ctrlcontrols` y usar el método correspondiente `next()`, `previous()`, `fastForward()` y `fastReverse()`. A esto te refieres?

Comment: En cuanto a lo del código, @Capt.Teach se refiere a que en lugar de poner una captura de tu código, pedimos que copies el código y lo pegues en tu pregunta.

Comment: laumrz a raiz de la respuesta de @Pikoh no se si con acelerar te refieres a aumentar la velocidad del video y adelantar al tipico boton que añade tiempo al video o avanza al siguiente espero tu aclaracion para modificar mi respuesta

Comment: @Capt.Teach agrega el `next` y el `previous` a tu respuesta y yo creo que con eso estaría completo, a falta de que el op confirme :) (y por favor, pon rebobinar...;P)

Comment: @Capt.Teach sí, con el botón de acelerar me refiero a aumentar la velocidad del vídeo (y decelerar sería para disminuirla) y con adelantar sería el típico boton para avanzar dentro del mismo vídeo, es decir, añadir tiempo al vídeo como tu has dicho (y retroceder sería al contrario). PD: perdón por poner captura del código en vez de copiarlo, ya lo sé para la próxima.

Comment: @Pikoh es verdad, se me había olvidado que existía la palabra rebobinar :) y gracias por tus consejos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar no he probado esto, solo he hecho una pequeña búsqueda en Google.

La clase `axWindowsMediaPlayer` tiene la propiedad `Ctlcontrols` como ya has visto con el `play()` esta propiedad al final llama a un interfaz [IWMPControls](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/iwmpcontrols--vb-and-c).

De esta interfaz puedes sacar algunas cosas que buscas:

- Adelantar : `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition += 10;`
- Retroceder : `axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition -= 10;`
- Acelerar : `FastForward()` Pone la velocidad del video 5 veces mas rapida
- Decelerar : `fastReverse()` En teoria lo que hace seria rebobinar el video a una velocidad de 5 veces
             aunque no estoy seguro mas info [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/wmplibiwmpcontrols-iwmpcontrols-fastreverse--vb-and-c)
- Avanzar : `Next()` Avanza al siguiente item de tu playlist
- Retroceder : `Previous()` Retroce al ultimo item que esta antes del item actual de tu playlist

Todo esto es solo leyendo la documentacion y no he probado nada , espero que te sirva para empezar.

Informacion sobre [axwindowsmediaplayer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmp/axwindowsmediaplayer-object--vb-and-c)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! En cuanto lo pruebe pondré por aquí si ha funcionado :)

Comment: @laumrz si te funciona, lo que debes hacer es aceptar la respuesta (la v que está a la izquierda debajo del 0) y votar positivamente. Como extra, puedes añadir un comentario, pero es lo menos importante.

Comment: Perfecto! Lo tendré en cuenta :)